# getting the image taken by camera on share button click

Tags: android, image, camera

I have an app. i want to share the photo taken by camera in my app. So when i am taking one camera and clicking the share button my app is also showing in the list of apps which can share the image.  And i am doing this by adding this intent filter into the menifest file:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
```

But when i am opening this activity  i need the pic taken by camera in an imageview. How can i do this ? Any idea, please share !!!! Thanks

Comment: Try this one no need to  set this intent-filter in mainfest.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440071/java-lang-runtimeexception-failure-delivering-result-resultinfo-when-capturing/18440280#18440280

Comment: @Android Killer Have you code even to capture the image from camera ?

Comment: @GrIsHu ig i can code then why i will ask question here. i searched the code but didn't fine how to get the image man.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia what u r giving that is wrong.

Comment: Do you want a code to capture image from camera and set that image in `ImageView` and then share it. Right ?